# Convert latex to wolframalpha.com compatible expression

Tags: wolfram-alpha

I have latex

```
\frac{-\left(2\left(b_{x}-a_{x}\right)\right)+\sqrt{\left(2\left(b_{x}-a_{x}\right)\right)^{2}-4\left(a_{x}-2b_{x}+c_{x}\right)\left(a_{x}-g_{x}\right)}}{2\left(a_{x}-2b_{x}+c_{x}\right)}
```

It's not malformed and renders as:

$$
\frac{-\left(2\left(b_{x}-a_{x}\right)\right)+\sqrt{\left(2\left(b_{x}-a_{x}\right)\right)^{2}-4\left(a_{x}-2b_{x}+c_{x}\right)\left(a_{x}-g_{x}\right)}}{2\left(a_{x}-2b_{x}+c_{x}\right)}
$$

Wolfram Alpha is ignoring it though:

[image]

How can I convert latex in general into a representation of an expression that wolframalpha will accept?

Comment: Can you post an example of Wolfram accepting LaTeX as input? That would be useful. This question is probably better suited for Mathematica.SE https://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro `simplify \frac{a}{2a}` works

Comment: Here's it simplified:
$$\frac{a_{x} - b_{x} + \sqrt{\left(a_{x} - b_{x}\right)^{2} - \left(a_{x} - g_{x}\right) \left(a_{x} - 2 b_{x} + c_{x}\right)}}{a_{x} - 2 b_{x} + c_{x}}$$
\frac{a_{x} - b_{x} + \sqrt{\left(a_{x} - b_{x}\right)^{2} - \left(a_{x} - g_{x}\right) \left(a_{x} - 2 b_{x} + c_{x}\right)}}{a_{x} - 2 b_{x} + c_{x}}

Comment: Weirdly, WA appears to dislike a space after \frac.   [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+%5Cfrac1%7Bx%2B1%7D) works, [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+%5Cfrac+1%7Bx%2B1%7D) does not.

Comment: Ok, I don't know. I actually would be interested in understanding this, it is useful to just feed LaTeX into Wolfram. My guess here is that it does not digest those subscripts $x$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro it looks like your guess might be right, replacing `a` with `a_x` or `a_{x}` in my previously commented working example leads to wolframalpha interpreting them as function applications $a(x)$

Comment: (2*a_{x} - 2*b_{x} + sqrt((-4*a_{x} + 4*g_{x})*(a_{x} - 2*b_{x} + c_{x}) + (-2*a_{x} + 2*b_{x})**2))/(2*a_{x} - 4*b_{x} + 2*c_{x})
$$$$
This should be digestible by wolfram

Comment: @Sam how did you generate that?

Comment: I've written a bunch of python functions that go to and from latex-style math equations to regular math equations. Would you like me to write them out in an answer?

Comment: @Sam definitely that would be a perfect answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some functions I use to convert $\LaTeX$ expressions to regular math expressions and vice versa:

```
from sympy import latex
from sympy import sympify
from sympy.parsing.latex import parse_latex
from pyperclip import copy

def LatexToMath(expr):
    # Input a string written in latex format. Have the math format copied to clipboard
    return copy(str(parse_latex(expr)))
def MathToLatex(expr):
    # Input a string written in regular math format. Have the corresponding latex format copied to clipboard
    return copy(latex(sympify(expr, evaluate=False)))
```